# beautifulsoup with same name tag, but different use

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, dataset

[image: samediv]

So i have this code

```
for j in links:
    Title = j.find('p').text.strip()
    Narration = j.find('p').text.strip()

    Link = j.find('a')['href'].strip()
    Date = j.find('time').text[-14:-1].strip()
    Label = '1'
```

But i have a trouble with it because theres 2 same `<p>` tag within the same `div`,but it has different use

```
Title = News Title
Narration = News Narration
```

is there any way to differentiate the `<p>` tags?

Comment: yes, inside class of "lnk-t", there's 2 kind of <p> in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs some HTML code to clarify, but as I understand correct you have to use `find_next('p')` on the first `find('p')`:

```
for j in links:
    Title = j.find('p').text.strip()
    Narration = j.find('p').find_next('p').text.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but i got"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_next'" error when i'm using this

Comment: My mistake, cause `Title` is already a string - updated answer.